# Press space to preview in LogMeIn

Tags: macos, keyboard, remote-control

Pressing space in Mac OS X on a file name, lets say on a CSV file, it shows me a preview of the file, which is a great feature.

When using LogMeIn to remote control other macs, this function is disabled.

Does someone know why?
Is there a workaround to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are presumably accessing the remote computer via the web portal?

The space bar is a common shortcut in most browsers to scroll the page (vertically down). I'm guessing that the browser is taking priority in this instance and not allowing the event to fall through to the remote OS. (?)

Comment: I'm not sure you're right. I'm using safari and iOS LogMeIn app, all keyboard shortcuts work but the space bar. Also, the browser opens a Java applet window.